# Iterate through a part of enumerator(external iterator)?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

If I want a part of an array I can use `[]` or `split`:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr[1..3]
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

But is there a 'general' version of `[]`? Can I apply it to any `Enumerator`?

```
enum = arr.each
enum.xxx_method(1..3) # is equal to arr[1..3].each
```

Of course you can use `arr[1..3]` directly. But I'm seeking a general way to handle any enumerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an enumerator, you can count on Enumerable methods `drop` and `take`:

```
# abstract if necessary as enum_slice(range)
enumerator.drop(2).take(3)
```

If that enumerator is an array you don't need to traverse it, check the method `Array#lazy_slice` that [I asked to be added](https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy/issues/1) to [enumerable_lazy](https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy) in relation with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865142/ruby-lazily-iterate-through-an-array):

```
require 'enumerable/lazy'

class Array
  def lazy_slice(range)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      range.each do |index|
        yielder << self[index]
      end
    end.lazy
  end
end

some_big_array = (0..10000).to_a # fake array, it won't generally be a range
p some_big_array.lazy_slice(9995..10000).map { |x| 2*x }.to_a
#=> [19990, 19992, 19994, 19996, 19998, 20000]
```